# Проблема установки Android Studio (repository)

Tags: android, android-studio

Установил Android Studio, после чего началась автоматически установска repository. Ценую ночь скачивался файл в итоге ничего не изменилось. Сколько весит этот файл и где его скачать самостоятельно?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Это кэш библиотек гугла. Нужно для того, чтобы когда в вашем проекте будут подключены какие-либо библиотеки поддержки от гугл (как AppCompat) студия не тянула их из интернета каждый раз, а брала в локальном кэше на вашем компьютере.

Отдельно ничего скачивать больше не нужно и визуально ничего измениться не должно, кроме отметки в SDK Manager о том, что локальный репозиторий установлен и какой ревизии.

Comment: Как отказаться от установки? Без надобности сейчас мне библиотеки.

Comment: я бы не советовал этого делать, приложение может потом просто не построится даже, у вас ограниченное место на диске?

Comment: Интернет плохой. Сколько это весит?

Comment: @ЕвгенийКалайда раз у вас что то уже скачалось, то смысла отказываться от установки нет никакого, а вообще в SDK Manager студии уберите галки напротив пунктов google repositiry и support repository

Answer (score 0):

Весит 339 мегабайт. Где скачать написано прямо в вашей фотографии. Только непонятно, что вы будете с ним делать после скачивания.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/294704)

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Вопрос: "_Сколько весит этот файл и где его скачать самостоятельно?_". На оба вопроса дан ответ.